# Properties of Sums of Legendre Symbols

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers, quadratic-residuosity

## Context

- An unknown modulus N with 8 unknown prime factors $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_7, p_8$
- a plaintext $m$ is encrypted with the formula $c = 2^m \mod N$
- the only things the attacker know are $c$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i)$ for any integer $a$ with $(a|p)$ being the Legendre Symbol of $a$ and $p$

## Attempts

Observation:

- $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i) = 0$ if $a = N$
- $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i) \in \{-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}$ if $a$ is not a multiple of one of the prime factors of $N$
- $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i) \in \{-7, -5, -3, -1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7\}$ if $a$ is a multiple of one of the prime factors of $N$ since $(p|p) = 0$
- From the definition of Legendre Symbols, if $a$ is a perfect square and not a multiple of the prime factors of $N$, $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i) = 8$
- The multiplication property of a Legendre Symbol applies

## Question

1. What Cryptosystem is this?
2. How can we retrieve the plaintext?

Comment: Are you sure the question asks to _retrieve the plaintext_, rather than _retrieve information about the plaintext_ (or select among few possible plaintexts, which is not trivial since we do not know $N$, apparently)? Half-baked idea: if you obtain the values of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^8\left(\frac a {p_i}\right)$ for $a=2$ (e.g. $2$) and $a=c$ (e.g. $8$), can that reveal something about $m$? Can asking for another $a$ (e.g. $a=c^2$) reveal more? What are the odds that you can't use this strategy to get any sure information about $m$? What if you make a single query?

Answer (score 1):

1. The system bears some similarity to the Maurer-Yacobi [non-interactive public key scheme](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46416-6_43.pdf) (an early approximation to identifier-based encryption) with $\alpha=2$, $r=8$. However, the M-Y system does not require disclosure of the sum of the Legendre symbols.
2. Note that if we can recover plaintexts, then we can solve discrete logarithms modulo each of the $p_i$ in the multiplicative subgroup generated by 2. One could do this by choosing each of the $p_i$ to be a prime of around, say, 512-bits. With some precomputation it should be possible to [solve discrete logarithms modulo these primes in roughly 36-core minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logjam_(computer_security)#Details) each and thus learn $m\mod {p_i-1}$. The Chinese remainder theorem can then be used to recover $m$.

To attack the system the first thought would be to factor the 4096-bit number $N$, though this is beyond the scale of the general number field sieve for which the largest number factored is 829-bits. Alternatively, one might hope that the elliptic curve method could identify the factors more cheaply. However the largest prime identified by ECM to date is [274-bits in size](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/records/top50.html).

No effective method using knowledge of Legendre symbol information has been found to significantly improve factoring methods. In particular, when factoring numbers of the form $p^2q$ (such as are used in the [Okamoto-Uchiyama cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okamoto%E2%80%93Uchiyama_cryptosystem)) where the adversary can know compute Legendre symbols modulo $q$, we do not know of a superior factoring method.

Comment: I wonder if this oracle giving $\sum_{i=1}^{8}(a|p_i)$ for any input $a$ could help factorization of $N=\prod p_i$ or the DLP modulo $N$ (but I do not immediately see how; also, we do not know $N$, apparently).

Comment: @fgrieu One feels that the strongest information comes when the sum (for non-square $a$) is $\pm 8$ so that we know that $a$ is a (non-)residue for all of the primes dividing $N$. Even given a stronger oracle that returns all of the Legendre information for all of the primes, I'm not aware of how to exploit that.

Comment: I see how we can use the oracle to recover one bit of $m$ with certainty, for all except <0.4% choices of $N$ (and test against that edge case). For the rest, I pass. Indeed, even knowing $\left(\frac a p\right)$ for any desired $a$ does not seem to allow finding large $p$.